# Android back button on ReactJs webview doesnt bring the control back to the last visited webview page

Tags: android, reactjs, routes, webview, single-page-application

I have an android project in which I am using ReactJs project as a WebView. Now, while performing router operations with controls inside webview works just fine, when I try to tap on hardware back button, it does not take me to previously opened page of WebView, instead its taking me to the Android app's last visited page.

Inside android app, post login, the user is navigated to ReactJs WebView.
Here lets suppose we have the WebView HomePage H, and other pages of WebView as O.
Everytime you come to the App, as per the logic, its checking if you are logged in or not, if you are then an API will return the URL of WebView and it opens that URL to access the page H of WebView.

Now if you navigate to page O from page H. Ideally on pressing of back button it should take you to page H without loading anything apart from APIs.
Instead its taking the controls back to the login check page of Native Android -> Check if user is logged in -> and eventually brings user to page H.

The issue is why the hardware back button doesnot work as per ReactJs's router setup since its accessing WebView which is a ReactJs project.